# Tikz Node Positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I trying to create a cover page using tikz and I would like to position a tabular element in a colored tikz rectangle both horizontally left justified and vertically centered.

In the attached example the tubular is being centered horizontally, as well at vertically.  How do I left justify the tabular, whilst keeping the vertical centering in the rect node?

Thanks

Stuart

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node (rect) [shape=rectangle, fill=red, minimum height=40mm, minimum width=\paperwidth, anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {};
                \node [anchor=west] at (rect.center) {
                    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
                     A & B \\
                    \end{tabular}
                };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Left justified means flushed to the right margin or flushed to the right edge of the paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not clear from the question whether "left justified" means flushed to the right margin or flushed to the right edge of the paper, I provide both options; locate the node at `(rect.east)` for the formaer or at `(current page text area.east|-rect.east)` (requires the `tikzpagenodes` package) for 
the latter. The `showframe` package is just to provide a visual guide to the page layout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{showframe}
    \begin{document}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node (rect) [shape=rectangle, fill=red, minimum height=40mm, minimum width=\paperwidth, anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {};
                \node [anchor=east,inner sep=0pt] at (rect.east) {%
                    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
                     A & B \\
                    \end{tabular}%
                };
                \node [anchor=east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.east|-rect.east) {%
                    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
                     A & B \\
                    \end{tabular}%
                };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]